# Getting a "Some required information missing" error testing a PayPal form

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

Getting error: Some required information missing from using this form:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="$id">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="PGZ7LZ2K66GLQ">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/GB/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online.">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

What information have I left out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is wrong with your hosted button id.May be wrong characters or you are using a LIVE paypal account hosted id.
You could try to generate new button.I just replaced the hosted button id with mine and it works.

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="3434">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="DG2WCMX8VL59Q">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/GB/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online.">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this wouldn't work with my site as I'm trying to do a subscription service

Comment: i dont understand, if you have copied your generated code correctly, your button code should work.

Comment: The code that is generated for the button works fine until I put sandbox infront of it

Comment: oh! which means the hosted_button_id belongs to live account. You cannot simply change the endpoint , for sandbox you will need to create a button from sandbox.paypal.com , alternatively you can create sandbox account at developer.paypal.com->Sandbox account->create Account and then use that credential to login to sandbox.paypal.com and create buttons

Comment: So do I need to create a button on a non live account? Im confused ha

Comment: yes, non live account is also called "Sandbox account" , sandbox.paypal.com :P